# Why aren't the Maven dependencies of my JAR being included in my WAR?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I have 2 Eclipse projects: (1) `my-library`, which builds `my-library-1.0.jar`; and (2) `my-deployable`, which builds `my-deployable-1.0.war`.

`my-library` is a dependency listed in the `pom.xml` of `my-deployable`.
`my-library` has 2 dependencies (2 Apache commons JARs) referenced in its `pom.xml`.

`my-library` is registered to my Nexus and I can retrieve it.

When I build `my-deployable-1.0.war` using goals `clean compile package`, `my-library-1.0.jar` is included in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder, but its 2 dependencies are not being included in the WAR where they are expected. I am under the impression I do not need to specify them explicitly in the `pom.xml` of `my-deployable` because they are already listed in the `pom.xml` of `my-library`.

**Why aren't dependencies for `my-library` JAR getting included in `my-deployable` WAR when built?**

The `pom.xml` for `my-library` reads:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.my</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>My Library</name>
  <description>This is my library JAR. It will be included in my WAR.</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
      <version>1.17</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </testResource>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/java</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
</project>
```

The `pom.xml` for `my-deployable` reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.12.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-deployable</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>My Deployable</name>
    <description>A deployable WAR for Spring Boot that has a dependency of my-library</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you deployed my-library to nexus since adding the Apache dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the JAR was registered to the in-house Nexus repository (this task is handed off to a secondary team), the `pom.xml` assigned to it was a Sonatype Nexus-generated `pom.xml`, not the one included with the JAR.  The generated file did not have dependencies associated.

The invalid, generated `pom.xml` is similar to:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my</groupId>
<artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<description>POM was created by Sonatype Nexus</description>
</project>
```

I discovered this by checking the `pom.xml` for each JAR in Nexus, comparing it to the same in each .m2 folder and each project; I hard-swapped the .m2 `pom.xml` with the file from the associated project, built my WAR, and the transitive dependencies appeared.

The next step is to repair all of the Nexus entries with the correct `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. They are meant to be included into the war.

Your dependencies and their scopes also look correct.

I would check the log of Maven for `[WARNING]`s and `[ERROR]`s. Maybe you have missing or invalid POM problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've created 2 skeleton projects with your poms above. The 'my-deployable' pom doesn't build as the spring-boot-maven-plugin is missing a mainClass definition

Error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.718 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-01T22:31:35+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/120M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.12.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project my-deployable: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.12.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
```

If I add the following section pointing at an class with an empty main method, I can compile and package the project

```
<configuration>
    <mainClass>com.my.MainClass</mainClass>
</configuration>
```

The resulting war file does indeed contain the dependencies of my-library. Either you've removed something key when you anonymised your pom, or you've missed the build error?

[image]

Comment: I have not had a problem building without the configuration, however, I added the `mainClass` as suggested.  The results were the same - there was no difference;the custom JAR dependencies were not pulled into the WAR.  I am not seeing any errors or warnings in the Maven Build logs.